# Bootstrap 3 колонки и 2 колонки

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть у меня строка `.row` , в ней три блока `<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 </div>">`. И получается так что если этих строк 2 и я сжимаю до размера sm экран, то у меня идёт такая очередность постов в строках: 2 1 2 1, а хотелось бы 2 2 2. Не знаю поняли ли вы меня, в общем когда пост переносится на след страницу, возле него пустота. Как это можно исправить? Эта проблема получается если нужна строка с нечетным количеством блоков сжать, и в итоге на меньшем экране должно быть четное количество постов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Бутстрап [переносит на следующую строку](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping) всё, что выходит за границу 12-колоночного макета. Поэтому можно завернуть все свои колонки в один-единственный ряд. Если колонки одинаковой высоты, то этого будет достаточно:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

/* Decorations */
.row {
  counter-reset: number;
}
[class*="color"] {
   height: 100px;
}
[class*="color"]:before {
  color: #fff;
  content: counter(number);
  counter-increment: number;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
}
.color-1 { background: #936; }
.color-2 { background: #693; }
.color-3 { background: #369; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 color-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 color-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 color-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 color-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 color-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 color-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 color-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 color-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 color-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 color-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 color-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 color-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. Но если колонки разной высоты, то они начнут цепляться друг за друга и макет скомкается. На этот случай предусмотрен [класс `.clearfix`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets). Колонки используют свойство `float`, а блок с `.clearfix` заставляет их начинать с новой строки.

   Чтобы показывать такой блок только при нужной ширине экрана, [добавьте классы](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes) `.visible-xs-block`, `.visible-sm-block`, `.visible-md-block` и `.visible-lg-block`.  Не забудьте предусмотреть появление `.clearfix` для экранов шире `1200px`:

   http://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/GjGyVo

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

/* Decorations */
.row {
  counter-reset: number;
}
[class*="color"]:before {
  color: #fff;
  content: counter(number);
  counter-increment: number;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
}
.color-1 { background: #936; height: 160px; }
.color-2 { background: #693; height: 120px; }
.color-3 { background: #369; height:  80px; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 color-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 color-2"></div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 color-3"></div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 color-1"></div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block visible-md-block visible-lg-block"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 color-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 color-3"></div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block visible-sm-block"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 color-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 color-2"></div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block visible-md-block visible-lg-block"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 color-3"></div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 color-1"></div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 color-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 color-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Глеб, огромное спасибо, именно 2-й пункт меня интересовал.

Answer (score 1):

В блоке row выводите все посты, а не делите по 3. Они перенесутся в соответствии с размером

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> Content </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> Content </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> Content </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> Content </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> Content </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> Content </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Как вариант - подходит, но посмотрите выше ответ Глеба, 2й пункт, здесь будут проблемы.

Comment: для современных браузеров, для решения проблемы разной высоты, можно добавить display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap; align-items: stretch; к блоку row и display: flex; к каждой колонке. В 4 версии бутстрапа это решение будет "из коробки"